# Lubuntu 20.04 won't boot after clean install

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I have Acer aspire 7720g. I do a clean install of Lubuntu 20.04. Install has complete without problems.When a go to restart wont boot. I don't know what the problems.I searched different forums and talking about uefi. In my bios I don't have uefi but only bios or legacy boot. Please help me and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my Acer 7720G and somehow solved it by following the second option given in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.

> 2nd option : install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu
>
> - either from an Ubuntu live-session (boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB then choose "Try Ubuntu") or from your installed Ubuntu session (if you can access it)
> - connect to the Internet
> - open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
> ```

Following the above, boot-repair app will appear on the screen. Proceed with **Advanced options** since **Recommended repair** did not solve the problem. In **Advanced options**, click the following (if I remember correctly!) and do not touch other settings already clicked by default.

- Reinstall GRUB
- Repair file systems
- Reset extra space after MBR (solves the [FlexNet] error)
- Uncomment GRUB_GFXMODE (solves the [out-of-disk] error)

And then **Apply** the changes. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Lubuntu 20.04 on an older computer and it would not boot.

I found that the Lubuntu (Linux) partition on the hard drive was not set as bootable.

My fix was to boot from the Lubuntu DVD into "demo" Lubuntu, install a disk utility program (using System Tools/Discover install Gnome Disk Utility.) and edit the hard drive partiton simply checking the "bootable" checkbox.

Now my older computer does boot up in Lubuntu 20.04 from the hard drive. My newer computer would boot, and doesn't care about the "bootable" settings.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: "My fix was to boot from the Lubuntu DVD into "demo" Lubuntu, install a disk utility program (using System Tools/Discover install Gnome Disk Utility.) and edit the hard drive partiton simply checking the "bootable" checkbox." --- This worked flawlessly for me as I had the same issue, altho' I used a bootable USB instead of a DVD.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by loading back into the original 'Try/Install Lubuntu' area and:

`ctrl + alt + T`

`sudo apt install gparted`

`gparted &`

Find the system drive, right click and modify the system flags to include `boot` and `bls_boot`

In particular, choosing `bls_boot` seems to have resolved it.

Comment: Thank you for this arcane knowledge! The bls_boot flag was EXACTLY what I needed! Surf Wisely.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your Lubuntu to your BIOS's boot options. I believe you need to select *EFI/grub/bootx64.efi*

Answer (score 0):

After reading these posts I disabled BIOS UEFI defaults and the system booted. Bios was also set to legacy and UEFI. The boot loader was install in the primary disk partition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).